# How do I import this API Java? CLASSPATH?

Tags: java, email

OS: MAC OSX Big Sur 11.2.1

I am trying to get the "TKLjavax.mail-1.5.6.jar" file to work/import into my code.

I have attempted to set my CLASSPATH, and this is what it looks like.

```
echo CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:/Users/name/Desktop/javaStuff/TKLjavax.mail-1.5.6.jar;.
```

and this is suppose to allow me to import these: (which are in the start of my Java File that holds my code)

```
import javax.mail.*;
import javax.mail.internet.*;
import com.sun.mail.imap.*;
```

I am getting an error though, which says:

```
error: package javax.mail does not exist
import javax.mail.*;
^
error: package javax.mail.internet does not exist
import javax.mail.internet.*;

error: package com.sun.mail.imap does not exist
import com.sun.mail.imap.*;
^
```

... and many more errors, where symbols of those imports can not be found.

**I am newer to Stack Overflow**, so please take it easy on me. I am just trying to get my code to work, I have tried many different ways to save the CLASSPATH, but I keep getting the same error.

I am almost positive this is the correct .jar file and would allow for these packages to work.

=========================================

**Add On:**

I have added a new CLASSPATH to my batch_profile

```
echo CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:/Users/name/Desktop/javaStuff/javax.activation-1.2.0.jar;.
```

> I do not know if this *new* CLASSPATH helps or not.

I have gotten the program to run via `javac -cp` and `java -cp` and my full line of code was

```
javac -cp /Users/name/Desktop/javaStuff/javax.activation-1.2.0.jar -cp /Users/name/Desktop/javaStuff/TKLjavax.mail-1.5.6.jar Example.java
```

**and**

```
java -cp /Users/name/Desktop/javaStuff/javax.activation-1.2.0.jar -cp /Users/name/Desktop/javaStuff/TKLjavax.mail-1.5.6.jar Example.java
```

**Now I am getting an error that says:**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/activation/DataHandler
```

Comment: What's in TKLjavax.mail-1.5.6.jar?  How are starting you application?

Comment: it is an API that allows you to use those imports. I am starting it with compiler on the command line with javac (name of my program).java

Comment: I would use an IDE like Eclipse or IntelliJ.  Doing it by hand is hard.  But to answer your question, what are you passing to javac.  Are you passing the classpath?

Comment: I'm passing javac the name of my java file (with my code) that has the those imports. My professor said something about me adding an activiation.jar to my classpath so I am going to try that. I will let you know.

Comment: Been a long time since I've uses javac, but I would use -cp and make sure what you are importing are in you jar files that you are putting in your import statement

Answer (score 2):

> These packages do not exist

No java tool in existence produces this exact error. Please paste the entire error, don't paraphrase it.

. `echo CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:/Users/name/Desktop/javaStuff/TKLjavax.mail-1.5.6.jar;.`

editing the global CLASSPATH var is not the recommended way to do this stuff.

Just run `javac -cp /path/to/jar *.java. Do you really have a file named` TKLJavax.mail`? **I think you forgot a forward slash in there, between TKL and javax**.

If you're convinced you got it all set up right, and that forward slash is not missing, it sounds like you have some custom-built javax.mail variant. So let's check if that jar is actually valid: `java -cp /Users/name/Desktop/javaStuff/TKLjavax.mail-1.5.6.jar com.sun.mail.imap.TheClassYouAreUsing` - check which error this gives you. It should give you: 'Main method not found in class ....'. If it gives you 'Could not find or load main class ....' - then that jar is corrupt or otherwise not useable on the classpath.

Comment: No that is just my paraphrase of the file name.

Comment: Okay so I ran my javac with the path and it runs... but I am getting this error Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/activation/DataHandler

Comment: @Bowen So that's a success, and a new problem. You need to provide your additional JARs as classpath arguments to the `java` command as well as to the `javac` command.

Comment: I have tried a couple different things and I added on to the original problem at hand via and edit.

Answer (score 1):

I can not use two -cp arguments for the javac and java line.

This is the correct way:

```
javac -cp /Users/name/Desktop/javaStuff/javax.activation-1.2.0.jar:/Users/name/Desktop/javaStuff/TKLjavax.mail-1.5.6.jar Example.java

java -cp /Users/name/Desktop/javaStuff/javax.activation-1.2.0.jar:/Users/name/Desktop/javaStuff/TKLjavax.mail-1.5.6.jar Example.java
```

The program complies and runs now.